# Configure Vaadin timeout (not session)

Tags: timeout, vaadin

My Vaadin application (version 8, but same behavior in Vaadin 24) has a button which generates a file to be downloaded.

> new FileDownloader(resource).extend(button)

In some cases the generation of the file takes very long and the user sees: Server connection lost, trying to reconnect...

The file then is never sent to the browser, but a java.io.EOFException is created.

How can I increase the timeout?

Comment: Maybe you should think about creating the file in the background and then display a notification when the file is ready

Comment: We use a background job for this and either display a progressbar, which is updated from the background thread (Server push) or have a "Hide" button where the user can minimize the generation process into the status line, and then open it from there when finished. BTW: What is "Very long" in your case?

Comment: The timeout might not even be in your hand (e.g. browser or proxy). Another option beside optimize the generation or do the download asynchronously could be to serve/stream the file through a regular endpoint "outside" of Vaadin (e.g. Spring Controller).